# laravel 5.2 table having name,email and password when email and password enter correct then only update or delete other wise don't edit the column

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image]

I having table employ columns

```
 name,
 employid, 
 email, 
 password, 
 salary and
 phone number,
```

what i want is when email and password is correct then only we edit the table column.

the email and password is not correct please create new column. email is unique. 
email and password is correct then edit that particular column other column not edit.

can u please expalin this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a request class in order to apply validation that will occur in all scenarios, from there take it a special handler method in the `Employ Controller`. In there you can apply the desired logic, example below:

```
public function employHandler(EmployRequest $request)
{
  $employ = new Employ;
  $record = $employ->where('email', '=', $request->request->email)
                   ->where('password', '=', $request->request->password)
                   ->first();

  if($record != null){
     $employ->update($request, $record->id);
  }else{
     $employ->store($request);
  }
}
```

I didn't add a check for delete since you have a button for it. When a user clicks on the delete button simply route them to the `Employ::delete()` method to handle that.